# Get global navigation items using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, global-navigation

I have used the SharePoint structural navigation.

I need to check the navigation node is exist or not, so I need to get all the navigation nodes using PowerShell.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User `TopnavigationBar` property from `$web.Navigation`. It will load all nodes from global navigation.

Use below code:

```
 $SPWeb=Get-SPWeb  "Url"
 $topnavigation = $SPWeb.Navigation.TopNavigationBar 
 foreach($node in $topnavigation) 
 {
     $node.Title
     //Your logic
 }
```

Comment: Yes, it retrieves all the global navigation items.but i have disabled the 
'Show pages' check box.so i dont need the pages navigation node. how to i do this?please suggest idea.

Comment: $node.Properties.NodeType -ne [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.NodeTypes]::Page , add this condition in foreach.

Comment: $subnodeGroup = $node.Children 
foreach($subnode in $subnodeGroup) 
 {
$subnode.Title
//your rest logic
}